# Svelte dynamic popup with different component

Tags: svelte

Do you have any example (without any kit) of a simple Svelte popup with different component inside?

So one popup that displays several models. The component handles the CRUD operations of the models. The popup handles only the popup close event.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Modal Component like below:

```
<script context="module">
  const modalList = [];
</script>

<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { modalStore } from "../stores";

  const store = modalStore(false),
    { isOpen, open, close } = store;

  const keydown = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (e.key === "Escape") {
        close();
      }
    },
    transitionend = (e) => {
      const node = e.target;
      node.focus();
    },
    modalAction = (node) => {
      const returnFn = [];
      if (document.body.style.overflow !== "hidden") {
        const original = document.body.style.overflow;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        returnFn.push(() => {
          document.body.style.overflow = original;
        });
      }
      node.addEventListener("keydown", keydown);
      node.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionend);
      node.focus();
      modalList.push(node);
      returnFn.push(() => {
        node.removeEventListener("keydown", keydown);
        node.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionend);
        modalList.pop();
        modalList[modalList.length - 1]?.focus();
      });
      return {
        destroy: () => returnFn.forEach((fn) => fn()),
      };
    };

  onMount(() => {
    if (autoOpen) open();
  });

  export let autoOpen = false;
</script>

<slot name="trigger" {open} />
{#if $isOpen}
  <div class="modal" use:modalAction tabindex="0">
    <div class="backdrop" on:click={close} />
    <div class="content"><slot name="content" {close} /></div>
  </div>
{/if}

<style type="postcss">
  .modal {
    @apply z-50 fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center opacity-100;

    .backdrop {
      @apply bg-white z-40 absolute w-full h-full opacity-30;
    }
    .content {
      @apply z-50 mx-8 sm:mx-20 md:mx-auto;
    }
  }
  .modal:not(:focus-within) {
    transition: opacity 0.3ms;
    opacity: 0.99;
  }
</style>
```

then use it in parent component like this:

```
<Modal>
  <button slot="trigger" let:open on:click={open}>Open the Modal</button>
  <div slot="content" let:close></div>
</Modal>
```

also for dynamic components:
https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-component